# IllegalStateException in Hibernate metamodel generation with maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, metamodel

I'm using hibernate-jpamodelgen to generate the metamodel classes using maven.

When i run **mvn clean package**, it works fine without any problem. But if i run the **mvn package** second time (without clean), I'm getting the following exception :

```
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_51). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: endPosTable already set
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.DiagnosticSource.setEndPosTable(DiagnosticSource.java:136)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Log.setEndPosTable(Log.java:350)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:667)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parseFiles(JavaCompiler.java:950)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:892)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:921)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1187)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:825)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

**Environment**:

```
JDK version : 1.8.0_51
Maven version : 3.3
Hibernate version : 4.3.7.Final
```

Snippet from my pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the Answer!...

It's a bug in **3.2** & **3.3** versions of **maven-compiler-plugin**.

When I run the '**mvn package**' second time, the previously generated source directory is added to the source path before the **generate-source** phase and it causes this **parser exception**.

Switching back to the older version (**<3.2**) of maven-compiler-plugin **fixes** the issue.

Note that the **incremental compilation** is **broken** in **3.0** & **3.1** versions of **maven-compiler-plugin**. So, I prefer to switch the **2.5.1** version of maven-compiler-plugin.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Have you submitted a bug report for this?

Comment: Many people reported this issue in github. One of them is : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-205

Comment: Since @eyes has now given a forward-going version to use try testing it with your app and if it works for you change your accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Same issue faced with gradle build as well. 
If you have previously metamodel classes available @ source-generate(please check the build.gradle file to check the path where your model classes being generated), this issue will come when run gradle build.

Solution : Delete the existing model classes and run gradle build. It should workout.

Comment: This is now also fixed for Gradle - see this link: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/4700#issuecomment-378721681 - I've tried it out with version 4.10.2. You have to use f.e. `dependencies { annotationProcessor 'org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.3.4.Final' }` and then `compileJava { options.annotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory = project.file(myDirectory) }`.

Answer (score 2):

This bug is fixed in the meantime. You should use maven compiler plugin 3.6 or higher:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Great. This solved my problem with hibernate, generate-sources, run-annotation-processors-only and Cobertura. Big combination, so I'm mentioning it to give someone else that combination to search on.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found another cause of this error: an old version of the maven-processor-plugin (2.1.0 in my case). I got the 'endPosTable already set' even when running mvn clean package. Upgrading the maven-processor-plugin and hibernate-jpamodelgen to the latest versions helped.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this error (happening in CI/CD but was not an issue locally) by removing the maven-processor-plugin. My intelliJ still picks up references to the modelgen classes and only required import of the dependancy